# How can I simply compare two timeseries of two differents perfomance tests?

Tags: performance, csv, testing

I'm looking for a simple tool to be able to compare two timeseries from two different tests.

For exemple, I'm recording the access time to a database when I delete 1000000 rows, one after another. Now I get two csv files:

- the first one with every tags and information about the test (database version, exe name, run params, etc)

```
startTime,clientComputerName,pid,testId
2022-09-29T09:20:16.453Z,COMPUTER-22,4608,A-1664443216
```

- the second one with every value of my timeserie in micro seconds

```
startTime,duration
5,140
146,145
291,146
438,21
460,21
482,21
504,24
529,25
555,22
578,21
600,24
624,21
646,21
668,23
692,21
```

I get several test info line and timeseries files.
With this I would like to load one or several selected tests (based on tags in test info file) and plot them on top of one another to compare them.

Here's an exemple of the desired result:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3HF6.png)

Now here's my problem,
I tried using plotly, but for this amount of point it gets two slow and I lose interactibility. I cannot down-sample to be able to investigate anomalies.
Kibana and Grafana are not options either since its datetime based (unless I'm missing something here).
I'd like to find something as simple as possible (tools like PowerBI might too complicated for this usage)

Do you know what I could use ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just found this website to find dataviz tools: https://datavis.tools/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.